# function depositTokens doesnt work in remix ethereum , please help

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-20, payable, payments

error in remix:

Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending? Internal JSON-RPC error. { "code": 3, "message": "execution reverted: ERC20: insufficient allowance", "data": "0x08c379a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001d45524332303a20696e73756666696369656e7420616c6c6f77616e6365000000" }

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract Staking {
  address owner;
  mapping(bytes32 => address) public whitelistedTokens;
  mapping(address => mapping(bytes32 => uint256)) public accountBalances;

  constructor() {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }

  function whitelistToken(bytes32 symbol, address tokenAddress) external {
    require(msg.sender == owner, "This function is not public");

    whitelistedTokens[symbol] = tokenAddress;
  }

  function getWhitelistedTokenAddresses(bytes32 token) external returns(address) {
    return whitelistedTokens[token];
  }

  function depositTokens(uint256 amount, bytes32 symbol) external payable {
    accountBalances[msg.sender][symbol] += amount;
    ERC20(whitelistedTokens[symbol]).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
  }

  function withdrawTokens(uint256 amount, bytes32 symbol) external {
    require(accountBalances[msg.sender][symbol] >= amount, 'Insufficent funds');

    accountBalances[msg.sender][symbol] -= amount;
    ERC20(whitelistedTokens[symbol]).transfer(msg.sender, amount);
  }
}
```

Comment: error in remix :   Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Internal JSON-RPC error. { "code": 3, "message": "execution reverted: ERC20: insufficient allowance", "data": "0x08c379a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001d45524332303a20696e73756666696369656e7420616c6c6f77616e6365000000" }

Comment: How did you get that error message? What function were you calling? Did you approve the contract to retrieve tokens?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the error right there. `insufficient allowance`. As you can see, you are using `transferFrom()` function in the `depositTokens()` function. For using transferFrom, you need to first approve the contract from your address to let contract use those tokens on your behalf.

So, create an instance of your token first and hit `approve` method with the Staking contrat as the spender. It will work fine.

```
approve("stakingAddress", "amount")
```

Answer (score 0):

Approving the staking contract and amount from my tokens main contract and it worked.

Thanks a lot for the help  @shubhamskatel